# Angular.js - Facebook page feed, display posts in list of cards, with fullscreen image gallery. Can someone help me out?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app, that fetches the Facebook page posts and display's them in custom css, within the app, that works just fine. I have two controllers, DashCtrl and MainCtrl, both work fine separately, the DashCtrl fetches the data and display's it within the app, i have added MainCtrl, to add the fullscreen photo functionality, and then ran in to problems trying to pass (not sure which is best btw...) the picture links, pictureArray or objects from DashCtrl --> MainCtrl. Can someone help me out? I've been at it for day's, but can't get the final pieces of code together..

The main idea, is to have the Facebook page posts, displayed in a list, as cards (which works fine!), and if user clicks the picture, or the button below it, to show the picture from that card in fullscreen, even better if user can scroll the images, like a gallery.

All the help i can get is really welcome! Thanks is advance!

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])


.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

function makeHttpRequest() {

try {return new XMLHttpRequest();}
catch (error) {}

try {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
catch (error) {}

try {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
catch (error) {}

throw new Error ("HTTP Request Could not be completed.");
}


var appID = "appID";
var appSecret = "appSecret";

var accessTokenRq = makeHttpRequest();
var httpString = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='+appID+'&client_secret='+appSecret;

accessTokenRq.open("GET",httpString,true);
accessTokenRq.send(null);

var access_token;

accessTokenRq.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if (accessTokenRq.readyState == 4) {

    access_token = accessTokenRq.responseText;
    //alert("It works!");

    var request = makeHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET",'https://graph.facebook.com/profile_id/posts?'+access_token+'&fields=id,message,picture,link,name,description,type,icon,likes,comments,created_time,from,object_id&limit=5)',true);
    request.send(null);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if (request.readyState == 4) {

        var response = request.responseText;
        console.log(response);

        var fbData = angular.fromJson(response);

        var data = fbData.data;

        var messageArray = [];
        var pictureArray = [];
        var likeArray = [];
        var dateArray = [];
        var linkArray = [];
        var typeArray = [];
        var commentArray = [];

        var objects = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          
          var entry = data[i];

          // Message
          if (entry.message) {
             var message = entry.message;
             messageArray.push(message);
          }
          else {messageArray.push(" ");}

          // Picture
          if(angular.equals(entry.type,"photo")) {
            var pic = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+entry.object_id+"/picture?type=normal";
            pictureArray.push(pic);
          }
          else if (angular.equals(entry.type,"link")) {
            pictureArray.push(entry.picture);
          }
          else {pictureArray.push("empty");}
          console.log(pic);
          console.log(entry.picture);
            
          // Likes
          if (entry.likes) {
            var likeData = entry.likes;
            likeArray.push(likeData.data.length+" Likes");
          }
          else {likeArray.push(" Likes");}

            
          // Date 
          var created = entry.created_time;
          var rawDate = created.split("T");
          var date = rawDate[0];

          var rawTime = rawDate[1];
          var time = rawTime.split(":");
          var betaTime = time[0]+":"+time[1];
          var finalTime = addOneHour(betaTime);
          dateArray.push(date+" - "+finalTime);

            function addOneHour(time) {
              var seperatedTime = time.split(":");
              var hourTime = seperatedTime[0];
              var returningTime = "";
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("00") > -1) {returningTime = "01";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("01") > -1) {returningTime = "02";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("02") > -1) {returningTime = "03";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("03") > -1) {returningTime = "04";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("04") > -1) {returningTime = "05";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("05") > -1) {returningTime = "06";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("06") > -1) {returningTime = "07";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("07") > -1) {returningTime = "08";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("08") > -1) {returningTime = "09";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("09") > -1) {returningTime = "10";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("10") > -1) {returningTime = "11";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("11") > -1) {returningTime = "12";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("12") > -1) {returningTime = "13";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("13") > -1) {returningTime = "14";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("14") > -1) {returningTime = "15";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("15") > -1) {returningTime = "16";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("16") > -1) {returningTime = "17";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("17") > -1) {returningTime = "18";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("18") > -1) {returningTime = "19";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("19") > -1) {returningTime = "20";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("20") > -1) {returningTime = "21";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("21") > -1) {returningTime = "22";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("22") > -1) {returningTime = "23";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("23") > -1) {returningTime = "00";}

                console.log(returningTime+":"+seperatedTime[1]);

              return returningTime+":"+seperatedTime[1];  

              }

          // Link
          if (entry.link) {linkArray.push(entry.link);}
          else {linkArray.push("empty");}

          // Comments 
          if (entry.comments) {
            var commentData = entry.comments;
            commentArray.push(commentData.data.length+" Comments");

          }
          else {
            commentArray.push("0 Comments");
          }


          typeArray.push(entry.type);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
          
          // Only Text 
          if ( (angular.equals(linkArray[i],"empty")) && (angular.equals(pictureArray[i],"empty")) ) {
            objects.push('<div class="list card"><div class="item thumbnail-left"> <h2>Matty Mode</h2><p>'+dateArray[i]+'</p></div><div class="item item-body"><p>'+messageArray[i]+'</p><p><span class="subdued">'+likeArray[i]+'</span>  <span class="subdued">'+commentArray[i]+'</span></p></div> <a class="button-block button" ng-click="openModal()" ng-controller="MainCtrl">Bekijk</a> </div>');
          
          }

          // No Link, picture availiable
          else if ( (angular.equals(linkArray[i],"empty")) && (angular.equals(pictureArray[i],"empty")) == false ) {

            objects.push('<div class="list card"><div class="item thumbnail-left"> <h2>Matty Mode</h2><p>'+dateArray[i]+'</p></div><div class="item item-body"><img src="'+pictureArray[i]+'" width=100%></img> <p>'+messageArray[i]+'</p><p><span class="subdued">'+likeArray[i]+'</span>  <span class="subdued">'+commentArray[i]+'</span></p></div> <a class="button-block button" ng-click="openModal()" ng-controller="MainCtrl">Bekijk</a> </div>');

          }

          // The rest 
          else {
            
            objects.push('<div class="list card"><div class="item thumbnail-left"> <h2>Matty Mode</h2><p>'+dateArray[i]+'</p></div><div class="item item-body"><a href='+linkArray[i]+' ><img src="'+pictureArray[i]+'" width=100%></img></a> <p>'+messageArray[i]+'</p><p><span class="subdued">'+likeArray[i]+'</span>  <span class="subdued">'+commentArray[i]+'</span></p></div> <a class="button-block button" ng-click="openModal()" ng-controller="MainCtrl">Bekijk</a> </div>');

          }

        }

        $scope.entries = objects;
        //console.log(objects);
      }
    }
  }

}


})

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
    
   $scope.aImages = [{
       'src' : 'http://ionicframework.com/img/ionic-logo-blog.png', 
       'msg' : 'Swipe me to the left. Tap/click to close'
     }, {
        'src' : 'http://ionicframework.com/img/ionic-logo-blog.png', 
        'msg' : ''
      }, { 
        'src' : 'http://ionicframework.com/img/ionic-logo-blog.png', 
        'msg' : ''
    }];
    
    //console.log(objects);
  
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('image-modal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
    });

    $scope.openModal = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0);
      $scope.modal.show();
    };

    $scope.closeModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.hide();
    };

    // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      $scope.modal.remove();
    });
    // Execute action on hide modal
    $scope.$on('modal.hide', function() {
      // Execute action
    });
    // Execute action on remove modal
    $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
      // Execute action
    });
    $scope.$on('modal.shown', function() {
      console.log('Modal is shown!');
    });

    // Call this functions if you need to manually control the slides
    $scope.next = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    };
  
    $scope.previous = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.previous();
    };
  
   $scope.goToSlide = function(index) {
      $scope.modal.show();
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
    }
  
    // Called each time the slide changes
    $scope.slideChanged = function(index) {
      $scope.slideIndex = index;
    };
  }
])

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  }
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})

.controller('FriendsCtrl', function($scope, Friends) {
  $scope.friends = Friends.all();
})

.controller('FriendDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Friends) {
  $scope.friend = Friends.get($stateParams.friendId);
})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };
});
```

```css
.transparent {
  background: transparent !important;
}
.image-modal {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}
.fullscreen-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 55px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* Fix modal backdrop for smaller devices */
@media (max-width: 679px) {
  .active .modal-backdrop-bg {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  .modal-backdrop-bg {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-view view-title="Title" style="background-color:#363636">
  <ion-content class="padding">
      <p style="text-align:center"><img src="img/mm_icon.png"></p>
      
    <div class="list" >
        <div ng-repeat = "entry in entries track by $index" ng-bind-html="entry" ng-click="openModal()" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

            <script id="image-modal.html" type="text/ng-template"> 
              <div class="modal image-modal transparent" ng-click="closeModal()"> 
                  <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" show-pager="false"> 
                      <ion-slide ng-repeat="oImage in aImages"> 
                          <img ng-src="{{oImage.src}}" class="fullscreen-image" /> 
                          <p class="info">{{oImage.msg}}</p> 
                      </ion-slide> 
                  </ion-slide-box> 
              </div> 
            </script>

        </div>
    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a custom factory/service to pass data from one controller to another ?

Answer (score 0):

Have had a look at [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)? Sounds like what you might need.

Answer (score 0):

You should lookt at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services.

You create one, and load it in your controllers.

For example, let's say that you've created a $transferService with an array that contain whatever you wanna pass between your controller and some method to add/delete/retrieve object.

In your DashCtrl you push data in it with $transferService.add(), and in your MainCtrl, you retrieve them with $transferService.retrieve().

Comment: Solved it, see my own answer for details. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was busy for a really long time to get the services working, tried different things, none of which worked, high chance, because, i know i'm a noob with javascript...

Though eventually i solved it very simply, by adding

```
$scope.pictures = pictureArray;
```

and adding this, to the IMG_Ctrl:

```
    $scope.aImages = [{
    'src' : $scope.pictures[0], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, {
    'src' : $scope.pictures[1], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[2], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[3], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[4], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, {
    'src' : $scope.pictures[5], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, {
    'src' : $scope.pictures[6], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[7], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[8], 
    'msg' : ''
    }, { 
    'src' : $scope.pictures[9], 
    'msg' : ''
}];
```

If someone has a good solution, to write the code with the pictures, to make it one statement, instead of 10, i'm all ears!